# Fetch conversions with FB Marketing API

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I fetch insights using the insights API from FB Marketing but noticed that the conversion metric is only facebook-internal conversions and doesn't include conversions through pixel etc.. Any way to get all conversions on an different breakdown levels?

Thanks